# Why http & https request is not getting cached in safari 10 - Macos?

Tags: http, https, safari, browser-cache, http-caching

why my api call is not getting cached in safari, where i am responding with

```
cache-control: max-age=86400, private
Expires:Tue, 20 Mar 2018 09:23:22 GMT
```

**EDIT 1**
**Note:**

1. In other browser it is working fine.
2. cache is enabled in my safari browser.

**EDIT 2**
**Headers Details**

```
Request Header
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/601.7.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.2 Safari/601.7.7
Cache-Control   max-age=0


Response header
Cache-Control   max-age=86400, private
Expires Wed, 21 Mar 2018 10:14:13 GMT
ETag    20e01cfc-c3ba-311b-b2d1-ee5e32b4fc32
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  109
Date    Tue, 21 Mar 2017 10:14:13 GMT
Content-Type    text/javascript
Server  Apache
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.10
Cache-Control   max-age=86400, private
X-FORWARDED-FOR {Host}
```

Comment: Is this a Safari specific problem? Ever observed in other browsers?

Comment: @shaochuancs yes this is safari specific problem... Can you please help me here.

Comment: Did you call your API in Ajax or call them in Safari address bar? If called from Safari address bar (type URL and parameters and then click Enter), Safari doesn't cache it. Refer to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99860/doesnt-safari-cache-pages

Comment: Can you show us specific requests that browser doesn't cache? You can use [Safari Web Development Tools](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to export [HAR](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/).

Comment: @Leanid Sorry I can give you only header details. Shall i give?

Comment: @Code, yes, sure.

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev done

Comment: `max-age=0` value of request `Cache-Control` header means that browser will ignore cached response. How did you perform that request?